# Elliptic curves for ECDSA

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

I'm trying to implement parameters generation for ECDSA according to SEC1 v2.0:

```
Input: The approximate security level in bits = t is {80, 112, 128, 192, 256}  
 Output: Elliptic curve domain parameters over Fp: T = (p, a, b, G, n, h)
```

Here's the 2nd step of the algorithm:

2. Select elements $(a, b)$ is $F_p$ to determine the elliptic curve $E(F_p)$ defined by the equation:

$E : y^2 = x^3 + ax + b \bmod p$,

a base point $G = (G_x, G_y)$ on $E(F_p)$, a prime $n$ which is the order of $G$, and an integer $h$ which is the cofactor $h = E(F_p)/n$, subject to the following constraints:

- $4a^3 + 27b^2 \neq 0 \bmod p$
- ## $E(Fp) \neq p$.
- $p^B \neq 1 \bmod n \space\forall\space 1 <= B < 100$
- $h <= 2 ^{(t/8)}$
- $n−1$ and $n+1$ should each have a large prime factor $r$, which is large in the sense that $log_n(r) > (19/20)$.

---

I haven't understood a lot of things in 2nd step.

1. <s>How to select `a` and `b` for E(Fp)? Should it be done randomly just to satisfy `4a^3 + 27b^2 != 0(mod p)` ?</s> Yes it should, as far as i've understood.
2. <s>How to find #E(Fp) -- the cardinality of E(Fp)?</s> -- Schoof or SEA algorithm.
3. **How to choose generator -- $G = (G_x, G_y)$ and find its order $n$?** -- Random point should be chosen on a curve. Again not pretty sure about it. 
   EDIT: The point has to have a prime order. **How can a point be chosen with a prime order?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to generate a point with order $n$ than to find out the order of a random point:

- Generate a random point $G'$ (generate random $x$ and solve for $y$)
- Compute $G = hG'$ (multiply by cofactor)

This is guaranteed to generate a point $G$ with order either $n$ or $1$ (the point at infinity). The chance of generating the point at infinity is negligible, but you can check for it and regenerate $G$ if you want.

This procedure is described in section 3.1.3.2 "Point Selection" in SEC1v2, where it computes a generator from a seed $S$. It is more convoluted since it generates points verifiably at random.

Comment: where n is ?.. Though the real problem is to find a point with a **prime** order.

Comment: You can find $n$ by factoring the order of the curve, which you have found with e.g. Schoof's algorithm. Then $n$ will be the largest factor, and $h$ is the order divided by $n$.

Comment: probably you should add last comment to your answer. Thank you.